# eslint npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist - Not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint

I am trying to clean up my Javascript code and then to migrate to typescript.  I installed node.js npm and eslint on Ubuntu 20.04.  I ran npm -init and eslint -init.

```
$ npx eslist util.js
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'eslist@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jcobban/.npm/_logs/2021-03-14T19_42_22_328Z-debug.log
Install for eslist@latest failed with code 1
$ npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 296 (6848713 bytes)
Index entries: 449
Finished in 0.367s
```

I cannot find any report on stackoverflow in over a year with an explanation of this error or how to get around it.

```js
$ more .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'eslist@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '/home/jcobban/.npm/_npx/96863',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose npm-session b1a2059d3c7803e8
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist 635ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist 391ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for eslist@latest 404 Not Found - GET https:/
/registry.npmjs.org/eslist - Not found
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1043ms
12 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist - 
Not found
12 verbose stack     at res.buffer.catch.then.body (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/
npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:104:15)
12 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:
7)
13 verbose statusCode 404
14 verbose pkgid eslist@latest
15 verbose cwd /home/jcobban/public_html/jscripts
16 verbose Linux 5.8.0-7642-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "eslis
t@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "/home/jcobban/.npm/_npx/96863" "--loglevel" "er
ror" "--json"
18 verbose node v10.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code E404
21 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist - Not found
22 error 404
23 error 404 'eslist@latest' is not in the npm registry.
24 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
25 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
26 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
27 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I entered the URL  https://registry.npmjs.org/eslist into my browser and got back {"error":"Not found"}

Note that I have NEVER used node.js or npm or npx before today so I have absolutely no experience to guide me.  I am merely going by what is in the page https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started.  I just want to clean up my code.

Comment: Is the script possibly supposed to be asking for https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint?  Requesting that package does work.

Comment: `"eslist" !== "eslint"`

Answer (score 3):

stupid typo.  I should have types eslint not eslist